# How to exempt a list item from iteration?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iteration

I have two lists of integers of equal length. I would like to add each element of the first list to its corresponding element of the second list using the line:

```
complete_list = [first_list[i] + second_list[i] for i in range(len(first_list))]
```

However, some elements of first_list are special numbers and I would like to exempt them from the above operation whilst having the other elements added to make complete_list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick an `if` at the end of your listcomp:

```
>>> first_list = [1,2,3,10]
>>> second_list = [10,20,30,50]
>>> special = {2, 3}
>>> [first_list[i]+second_list[i] for i in range(len(first_list)) if first_list[i] not in special]
[11, 60]
```

Although I'd probably use `zip` here:

```
>>> [a+b for a,b in zip(first_list, second_list) if a not in special]
[11, 60]
```

If you want `a` to pass through unadjusted, you could move the `if` and use the `X if Y else Z` ternary syntax:

```
>>> [a+b if a not in special else a for a,b in zip(first_list, second_list)]
[11, 2, 3, 60]
```

Comment: How do you keep the elements from the special list in the complete_list at its original location?

Comment: So for those you want "a" and not "a+b"?

Comment: I want to exempt certain characters from the adding operation. So let's say that...

first_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
second_list = [6,7,8,9,10]

I want to add the two lists together, but exempt the 3s in first_list from the operation. So my final answer would be...

complete_list = [7,9,3,13,15]

When I followed your first instructions, it entirely skipped over the 3 and the output list contained only 4 elements (supposing I used this hypothetical scenario).

Comment: Sure, the second case will handle that.

Comment: @user123288 it's interesting how DSM and I came to the same thing but two different ways :)

Comment: @user123288: the last line.  It translates into English as "make a list using this rule: for every pair a and b, give me a+b if a isn't in special, otherwise just give me a".  Hence the "2,3" in the final list, because those are the elements in special, and it didn't do the addition.

Comment: Ugh, so sorry.....just figured it out and deleted comment. Excellent. Thank you, sir/madam.

Comment: Type print `zip(first_list, second_list)` at the console.  Then try `for a,b in zip(first_list, second_list): print a,b` to get the idea.  A list comprehension is just a `for` loop in disguise, where you put the loops on the right and the expression to want to append to the list on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to write your original example as:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

from operator import add
c = map(add, a, b)
# [5, 7, 9]
```

Then, if you only want elements to "not add" depending on criteria on `a`, then build a generator over `b` referencing the corresponding element on `a` and make it `0` for a no-op.

```
special = {2}
b2 = (j if a[i] not in special else 0 for i, j in enumerate(b))
map(add, a, b2)
# [5, 2, 9]
```